# Running a spring boot app from cron

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot `CommandLineRunner` app. I need to set up a cron job for some tests. How can I set up a cron job to call the app every 15 min? I am using `mvn spring-boot:run` from the app root to run to app.

Answer (score 2):

What platform are you on? If you are on Linux, the simplest way would be to create a script that runs your app either through maven or from a pre-built JAR and [add the script to crontab](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) using this expression as a template `*/15 * * * * /path/to/script`

Alternatively, you could do the [scheduling within your app](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Thanks I just build a JAR file and going to use it in crontab.

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I am now facing an issue with running the script via the cron tab on Linux. The spring boot application doesn't seem to be picking up the application.properties file placed in the same folder as of the shell script file. However, there are no problems if we login to the box via putty and invoke the shell script file manually. I tried setting up the permissions for the user on the file etc., but nothing worked. Any ideas here?